# Importing Cartthrob Orders Data with DataGrab

Tags: cartthrob, import, export, datagrab

I'm using Export It to export CartThrob orders channel data, and import in to another site using DataGrab.

When importing the orders channel with DataGrab one of Custom Fields is "Order Items" (which is a CartThrob Order Items field type). However, the corresponding custom fields options in the "Value" column are individually listed like this:

- order_items/product_title - eg, Waiting Here For You
- order_items/product_quantity - eg, 1
- order_items/product_price - eg, 0.00
- order_items/product_price_plus_tax - eg, 0
- order_items/product_weight - eg, 0
- order_items/product_shipping - eg, 0
- order_items/product_no_tax - eg, 1
- order_items/product_no_shipping - eg, 1
- order_items/product_extra - eg,

I need to assign all these values to the single Order Items field.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataGrab does not currently support importing into the CartThrob Order Items field type.

Third party field type support often needs to be added individually to DataGrab (as you've noticed in this case you need to add several values into a single field, so it needs its own interface to configure the import).

I try to support the most common field types and those where there is enough demand. It should not be too hard to add simple support for this, though. Can you contact me on support@brandnewbox.co.uk and I'll see what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you moving data from CartThrob 1 to CartThrob 2 installation? If so, I'd suggest you using CartThrob Updater (should be available for download in your cartthrob.com account, if it's not - contact the developers)